# asp.net core post json data with name property with too slow with non localhost url

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

Create asp.net core web api project in visual studio (dotnet core 2.0) 
it will create a values controller with get,post,put and delete method

update the program.cs to make the api accessible in non localhost interfaces also.

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) => 
   WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:61160")
                .Build();
```

run the application and post {"name":"abc"} to the http://{machine}:61160/api/values url. it will take more than 6 seconds to get the response. if you change the url to localhost or rename the name property in the json to something else you will get immediate response.

does anybody faced this weird issue?

here is the code for default controller, it is just the auto generated sample controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace TestApp.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post()
        {
         var data =new StreamReader(Request.Body).ReadToEnd();
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does only the first request need so much time?

Comment: the issue  happens always if you post any json with name property and the url is this ur machine name or ip, if you use localhost for the same data it will work fine.

Comment: show your controller also

Comment: It does not answer your question about the different duration. But what's the sens of sending  {"name":"abc"} if your controller only receives a string?

Comment: i am facing the issue in some other project. to isolate the problem i have tried it in an new project. anyway i have updated the post method to read request body.